# Can't do factory reset on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I can't reset my Galaxy Tab 2 to factory settings. I know that you can when turning it on but the problem is that I installed a sort of ios onto the device and have forgotten the password and it won't let me turn it off without being logged in, but I can't unlock it.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

According to [Verizon](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-63071/), if you cannot perform a factory reset from the **Settings** app, you can perform one by following these steps:

> 1. Power the device off.
>
>    1. Press and hold the **Power key**.
>    2. Select **Power off**.
>    3. Select **OK**.   *Note: If the screen doesn't respond to input, press and hold the **Power button** for 10-15 seconds.*
> 2. Press and hold the **Volume up key** then press and hold the **Power key**.   *Note: USB cable must be disconnected.*
> 3. When the Samsung logo appears, release the **Volume up key** and **Power key**.
> 4. From the Android system recovery screen, press the **Volume keys** to select wipe data / factory reset then press the **Power key**.
> 5. Press the **Volume keys** to select Yes -- delete all user data then press the **Power key**.
> 6. Press the **Volume keys** to select reboot system now then press the **Power key**.
> 7. Perform [Initial Activation and Setup](http://www.verizonwireless.com/content/support/devices/knowledge_base.html/60869).

You can read more at the [Verizon website (Tab 2 Troubleshooting: Hard Reset)](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-63071/).

Answer (score 1):

You can wipe your phone straight from your computer using Android Device Manager, by going to the Play Store website on your computer, clicking the settings button, and selecting Android Device Manager.  Then, select your phone if it isn't automatically selected, and click wipe.

Comment: What if my device isnt connected to device manager

Comment: If you haven't set it up on your phone, then this won't work, but if you mean that it just isn't connected to WiFi, then once it is connected to a network it will factory reset it.